# How to set value without setter method?

Tags: java

In the below code snippet how can I set the value of *a* and *b* without using the setter method? Is it possible? Can I call the private constructor in the public constructor?

```
public class ABC {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public ABC() {     
    }

    private ABC(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

ABC abc = new ABC();
```

Comment: You could use reflection, but it would be inexpressive and error-prone. What are you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a setter?

Comment: Why so ? Please help to understand people that asks "How do to that stuff WITHOUT the tool made for doing it"

Comment: @Julia Thanks for your comment. Actually, I can use the setter method. But I am curious to know is it possible or not?

Comment: It's possible. @InfiniteRecursion's answer is the one I would've written, but I also suspected (wrongly, it appears now) that there might be more to the question, e.g. an XY Problem, of sorts.

Comment: This probably isn't an option in your case, but making a and b public fields would allow you to change their values without the need for a method.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Java reflection, but this is considered to be bad practice and should be avoided. However, if you really need to:

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
Field abc_a = abc.getClass().getDeclaredField("a");
abc_a.setAccessible(true);
abc_a.set(abc, 20);
```

**Explanation**

```
Field abc_a = abc.getClass().getDeclaredField("a");
```

In java, there is a set of tools called Reflection, whose intended use is to allow for fields in classes to be dynamically set. A practical use of this is the GSON library, which reads JSON and automatically fills in the corresponding values in a class.

Every class has a `Class` object to assist with reflection, and every instance of an object has a method called `getClass()`. Calling this method will give you the `Class` object representing that class and using that, you can then invoke the `getDeclaredField(fieldName)` method which will return a `Field` object that allows you to do a variety of things to that field, one of which is setting the value.

```
abc_a.setAccessible(true);
```

Because the field being referenced to is private, this must be invoked to allow it to be accessed. If it was public, this step could be omitted.

```
abc_a.set(abc, 20);
```

This finally changes the value of the field `a` in the `ABC` class. The first parameter is the object you wish to change the value of, and the second parameter is the new value. Note that Field objects don't store class information, so if you wished to change the value of a different instance of `ABC`, you could use the same Field object and just change the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your actual question is

> Can I call the private constructor in the public constructor?

and nothing really related to setters.

Yes, you can call one constructor from another. In your example code this would look like this:

```
public ABC() {
    this(0, 0); // initialze a and b via the private constructor
}
```